# Reading RDF data into Apache Jena model without knowing language

Tags: java, rdf, jena, virtuoso

I have a website where a user can paste some RDF data, which then needs to be uploaded into a Virtuoso database on the backend side.

I am looking for a way to read the RDF data into an Apache Jena Model instance without specifying the language of the data (ex. Turtle), since I want the user to be able to upload RDF in any format. Ideally I would like to avoid having to ask the user to choose which format the data is in.

Is there a way to do this? As all the methods I have seen require specifying the language. If not, is there some way to upload the data directly to Virtuoso without using Apache Jena and without specifying the language?

Comment: Apache Jena uses file extension for the syntax determination. Otherwise the only way is to try. Because it is files, you can retry different languages.  In practice, a small amount of sniffing the file before trying to parse it will work for most cases to try the most likely first. e.g does it start "<rdf:RDF", that highly likely to be RDF/XML. Turtle parses N-Triples. JSON-LD starts "{" (so can Trig files but this would be unusual so using it to "best guess" and backing out and retrying would work).

Comment: If the info above proves insufficient, there are [many ways to load RDF data into Virtuoso](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtRDFInsert), whether or not Apache Jena is part of the mix, whether or not you know the serialization of the data.